# Find how many times a char is included into an array of names

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to do the following exercise in JavaScript: I need to return the number of times the letter 'l' is used inside an array of names.

This is an example of the array I have to use:

```
["earth (c-137)","abadango","citadel of ricks","worldender's lair","anatomy park","interdimensional cable","immortality field resort","post-apocalyptic earth","purge planet","venzenulon 7","bepis 9","cronenberg earth","nuptia 4","giant's town","bird world","st. gloopy noops hospital","earth (5-126)","mr. goldenfold's dream","gromflom prime","earth (replacement dimension)","testicle monster dimension","signus 5 expanse","earth (c-500a)","rick's battery microverse","the menagerie","earth (k-83)","hideout planet","unity's planet","dorian 5","earth (unknown dimension)","earth (j19ζ7)","roy: a life well lived","eric stoltz mask earth","earth (evil rick's target dimension)","planet squanch","glaagablaaga","resort planet","interdimensional customs","galactic federation prison","gazorpazorp"]
```

Note that the letter 'l' might be repeted inside a single name.

Is there any JS method I could use to do this ? I've tried with indexOf but couldn't make it work

Comment: Use nested loops: The outer loop iterates over the strings in the array, the inner loop iterates over the characters in the string. When the letter is matched, increment the counter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
myStr.split('<my_char>').length - 1.
```

This splits the string everytime you see the char you want and returns the number of strings after splitting at the delimiter minus 1 which is exactly what you want. Do this after converting the array of strings to a single string. myStr = myStrArray.toString();

Comment: They have an array of strings, not one string.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const stringArr = [
  'earth (c-137)', 'abadango', 'citadel of ricks', 'worldender\'s lair', 'anatomy park', 'interdimensional cable',
  'immortality field resort', 'post-apocalyptic earth', 'purge planet', 'venzenulon 7', 'bepis 9', 'cronenberg earth',
  'nuptia 4', 'giant\'s town', 'bird world', 'st. gloopy noops hospital', 'earth (5-126)', 'mr. goldenfold\'s dream',
  'gromflom prime', 'earth (replacement dimension)', 'testicle monster dimension', 'signus 5 expanse', 'earth (c-500a)',
  'rick\'s battery microverse', 'the menagerie', 'earth (k-83)', 'hideout planet', 'unity\'s planet', 'dorian 5',
  'earth (unknown dimension)', 'earth (j19ζ7)', 'roy: a life well lived', 'eric stoltz mask earth',
  'earth (evil rick\'s target dimension)', 'planet squanch', 'glaagablaaga', 'resort planet',
  'interdimensional customs', 'galactic federation prison', 'gazorpazorp'
]

const result = stringArr
  .map(item => item.split('l').length - 1)
  .reduce((acc, value) => acc + value, 0)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering.. It works great for my code..
Could you explain me how did you use the reduce method there please? I still struggle with that method.

Comment: After _map_ you have: [ 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, ... ]. _reduce_ takes that as input and loops over it. _acc_ stands for _accumulator_, it is the result of the previous step, with the exception of the very first step, in which case the second argument is used, in that case the zero in _.reduce(..., 0)_. So after the first step, you would have _0 + 0_, then _0 + 0_, then _0 + 1_, then _1 + 2_, etc. Note: Another good variable name for  _accumulator_ could also be _carry_ or _carryOver_.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using the array method [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop

```js
const stringArr = ["earth (c-137)","abadango","citadel of ricks","worldender's lair","anatomy park","interdimensional cable","immortality field resort","post-apocalyptic earth","purge planet","venzenulon 7","bepis 9","cronenberg earth","nuptia 4","giant's town","bird world","st. gloopy noops hospital","earth (5-126)","mr. goldenfold's dream","gromflom prime","earth (replacement dimension)","testicle monster dimension","signus 5 expanse","earth (c-500a)","rick's battery microverse","the menagerie","earth (k-83)","hideout planet","unity's planet","dorian 5","earth (unknown dimension)","earth (j19ζ7)","roy: a life well lived","eric stoltz mask earth","earth (evil rick's target dimension)","planet squanch","glaagablaaga","resort planet","interdimensional customs","galactic federation prison","gazorpazorp"]


let count = 0;

stringArr.forEach((string) => {
  for (let letter of string) {
    if (letter.toLowerCase() === "l") count += 1;
  }
});

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple regex that matches the character that you want to match with while iterating over the array items.

```js
const arrayToSearch = ["earth (c-137)", "abadango", "citadel of ricks", "worldender's lair", "anatomy park", "interdimensional cable", "immortality field resort", "post-apocalyptic earth", "purge planet", "venzenulon 7", "bepis 9", "cronenberg earth", "nuptia 4", "giant's town", "bird world", "st. gloopy noops hospital", "earth (5-126)", "mr. goldenfold's dream", "gromflom prime", "earth (replacement dimension)", "testicle monster dimension", "signus 5 expanse", "earth (c-500a)", "rick's battery microverse", "the menagerie", "earth (k-83)", "hideout planet", "unity's planet", "dorian 5", "earth (unknown dimension)", "earth (j19ζ7)", "roy: a life well lived", "eric stoltz mask earth", "earth (evil rick's target dimension)", "planet squanch", "glaagablaaga", "resort planet", "interdimensional customs", "galactic federation prison", "gazorpazorp"];

const REGEX_MATCH = /l/ig;

function getCount(array, regex) {
  const matchCount = array.reduce((memo, item) => {
    const matches = item.match(REGEX_MATCH);

    if (matches && matches.length > 0) {
      memo += matches.length;
    }

    return memo;
  }, 0);

  return matchCount;
}

const count = getCount(arrayToSearch, REGEX_MATCH);

console.log(`count is ${count}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = ["earth (c-137)", "abadango", "citadel of ricks", "worldender's lair", "anatomy park", "interdimensional cable", "immortality field resort", "post-apocalyptic earth", "purge planet", "venzenulon 7", "bepis 9", "cronenberg earth", "nuptia 4", "giant's town", "bird world", "st. gloopy noops hospital", "earth (5-126)", "mr. goldenfold's dream", "gromflom prime", "earth (replacement dimension)", "testicle monster dimension", "signus 5 expanse", "earth (c-500a)", "rick's battery microverse", "the menagerie", "earth (k-83)", "hideout planet", "unity's planet", "dorian 5", "earth (unknown dimension)", "earth (j19ζ7)", "roy: a life well lived", "eric stoltz mask earth", "earth (evil rick's target dimension)", "planet squanch", "glaagablaaga", "resort planet", "interdimensional customs", "galactic federation prison", "gazorpazorp"]

const howMany = (data, char) => data.join('').match(new RegExp(char, 'g')).length

console.log(howMany(data, 'p'))
```